# App is published but it is not seen in more from developers page

Tags: android, google-play

I have published my app and am not able to see the app while searching it. In my developer console it shows it is published also if i go to the developers page to see my newly published app but that is not seen. All other apps are visible.

I searched with the package name in play store that time it is visible. whats wrong here? Please help.

Comment: any special non English characters used in the app name? I had that before which made me unable to search it.

Comment: what's your app package name? @user2269164

Comment: com.allnetbanking is my package name

Comment: no only english name

Comment: You have to wait for some hours. App wont be published that fast. You have to wait for 2 3 hours. One of my app took 2 hours to get published.

Answer (score 0):

Go to google play developer console and open app and check **View in Play store** of it redirected to your app it means its ok and your app take time to locate in play store

[image]

Comment: Yes i am able to see my app as per you mentioned. So it will take sometime? normally it wont take this much time?

Comment: ya some time it take 12 or more hours to locate in play store this happen with my one app.